# Root Path Problem in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in my application a link button is there when i click on it it redirect to another page. But when i click on that page it is giving error like this...

Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a link that tries to go above the root of the website.

For example:

```
http://example.com/..
```

Solution? Don't do that.

Comment: Possibly the most universally applicable solution I've come across :)